# Repeated balanced k-fold cross validation using caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I would like to perform repeated k-fold cross validation using the `caret` package. This can be specified in the `trainControl()` function.

My question is, are the folds created using `trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=k, repeats=n)` balanced? Are these k-folds generated the same way as the balanced ones generated by `createFolds()`?

---

For clarity, here are examples of balanced and unbalanced k-folds:

The `iris` species breakdown:

```
table(iris$Species)
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     50         50         50
```

Now, we create random unbalanced and balanced folds:

```
k <- 10

unbalanced <- sample(rep(seq(k), length=length(iris$Species)))

bList <- createFolds(iris$Species, k)

# Below, we reformat the list of folds
balanced <- rep(-1, length(iris$Species))
for (i in seq_len(k)) balanced[bList[[i]]] <- i
```

Now, we visualize the class breakdown for each set of k-folds.

```
classBreakdownTable <- function(i, folds) table(as.factor(iris$Species)[which(folds == i)])

sapply(seq_len(k), classBreakdownTable, unbalanced)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# setosa        4    6    8    4    4    4    7    6    5     2
# versicolor    5    5    1    5    5    7    4    6    6     6
# virginica     6    4    6    6    6    4    4    3    4     7

sapply(seq_len(k), classBreakdownTable, balanced)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# setosa        5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5
# versicolor    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5
# virginica     5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

If the `method = "repeatedcv"` it calls on the function `createMultiFolds`, which internally calls on `createFolds`, but n times as specified in `repeats = n`